# Document Types in a document-based Cocoa application

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I am doing a document-based application that needs to work with images. While I know iOS I am new to Cocoa document-based apps, and need some input on best practices regarding document types.

I want the app to open different kinds of images (JPG, GIF, PNG, etc.).

In the target settings, do I add one document type for each image type, i.e. ending up with multiple document types. Or do I add just a single document type and then add all the image extensions in the "Extensions"-field.

It might not matter but is there a best practice here?

Answer (score 1):

After doing some more research online, it seems the way to go is to create one document type for each file type.

So I created a document type for JPEGs using the extensions jpg, jpeg, JPG, and JPEG.
Likewise I created one for PNG, one for GIF, one for TIFF, etc.